# Question about equivalence of infinite sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If there is a one to one correspondence between sets, then they are said to be equivalent. Explicitly, $A$ is equivalent to $B$, denoted $A \sim B$, if there is a one to one and onto function from $A$ to $B$. It can be shown that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation. In particular, this implies that if $A \sim B$ and $B \sim C$, then $A \sim C$.

Here is my question:
Now consider the intervals $I_n=[0,1/n]$. Then $I_1 
\sim I_{2} \sim I_3...$ From this we have that $I_1 \sim I_n$ for all $n$. Now $\lim _{n \to \infty}I_n=\{0\}$. So $I_n \sim \{0\}$. However, this is not the case.

I am thinking that what went wrong here is that $I_1 \sim I_n$ does not imply that $I_1 \sim \lim_{n \to \infty} I_n$. Does that mean that the transitivity property of equivalence relation doesn't extend to infinity?

Comment: why should that equivalence be "continuous" in any sense?

Comment: The simple answer is that you can't pass limits like that. While it is true that $I_1 \sim I_n$ for all $n$, infinity is not a natural number, so we cannot say $I_1 \sim I_\infty$ without further investigation (and as it obviously turns out, it's not the case). Also, limits for sets requires some form of a metric, so one usually avoids this for nested sets by writing $I_\infty = \cap_{n=1}^\infty I_n$, which is well-defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a good counterexample of $I_1 \sim \lim_{n\to \infty} I_n$ right there, so yes.  It seems natural that this example doesn't work; maybe I can help convince you:

Let $f_n:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by $f_n(x) = x/n$.  Then $f_n$ is a one-to-one and onto map of $[0,1] = I_1$ to $I_n$.  The transitive property holds because if $I_{\ell} \sim I_m \sim I_n$, then we have bijections $g:I_{\ell} \to I_m$ and $h: I_m \to I_n$, so $h\circ g$ is a bijection between $I_{\ell}$ and $I_n$.  In our case, $f_n \circ f_m^{-1}$ gives a bijection of $I_m$ onto $I_n$, demonstrating that.

The problem in taking the limit is that $\displaystyle f(x) := \lim_n f_n(x) = \lim_n x/n = 0$ for all $x$.  Basically, we're trying to `divide by infinity' in some sense, and this operation is not a $1-1$ map.

Because the setting was analytic (multiplication provided the mapping) we were able to talk about limits of these maps, and in this setting we could phrase your statement as

---

"Limits of one-to-one functions are not necessarily one-to-one."

Comment: Ah! the limit of one to one functions is not necessarily 1-1....this is insightful..thank-you!